# Create loop/function to remove negative varImp results

Tags: r, regression

I would like to create the loop which is going to model data, get the variable importance, assign the negative values/importance columns and filter them from the data and model it again **until there are no negative values**. Here below you can see the example code for creating the model and getting variable importance:

```
library(party)
library(caret)
model_cforest <- cforest(drat~.,data=mtcars,controls=cforest_unbiased())
cforest_var <- varImp(model_cforest,conditional=TRUE)
```

As we can see *cforest_var* gives us this table:

```
          Overall
mpg   0.009778909
cyl   0.033507134
disp  0.056359569
hp    0.000000000
wt    0.044186730
qsec  0.000000000
vs   -0.000309504
am    0.050791540
gear  0.060967894
carb  0.000000000
```

On base of this table i would like then to remove the column *vs* (which has negative value) and run the `cforest` model again (and if there is again negative value, remove it and run model until there are no negative values).

Final result should be a table with the most important variables.

Here is as far as i got:

```
removeNeg <- function(data){
  model_cforest <- cforest(drat~., mtcars,controls=cforest_unbiased())
  cforest_var <- varImp(model_cforest,conditional=TRUE)
  varImp_neg <- row.names(cforest_var)[apply(cforest_var, 1, function(u) any(u < 0))]
}
```

but i have feeling that it is wrong direction and i stucked in one place.Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `recursion` whereby you call the function within itself to perform the operation again

```
removeNeg <- function(dat){
  model_cforest <- cforest(drat~., data=dat,controls=cforest_unbiased())
  cforest_var <- varImp(model_cforest,conditional=TRUE)
  varImp_neg <- rownames(cforest_var)[cforest_var$Overall<0];varImp_neg
  if(length(varImp_neg)) removeNeg(dat[setdiff(names(dat),varImp_neg)])
  else cforest_var
}

removeNeg(mtcars)
         Overall
mpg  0.008729557
cyl  0.017711035
disp 0.052728670
hp   0.000000000
wt   0.069339311
qsec 0.000000000
am   0.038151787
gear 0.073904189
carb 0.000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution using while `loop`

Function to run `cforest` model on given data:

```
getForest <- function(data) {
    library(caret)
    library(party)
    model_cforest <- cforest(drat ~ ., data, controls = cforest_unbiased())
    varImp(model_cforest, conditional = TRUE)
}
```

Function that runs `while` loop if there are any negative `varImp` results.

```
getForestRemove <- function(data = mtcars) {
    resultModel <- getForest(data)
    resultSign  <- sign(resultModel$Overall)
    while(any(resultSign == -1)) {
        resultModel <- getForest(data[c("drat", rownames(resultModel)[resultSign != -1])])
        resultSign  <- sign(resultModel$Overall)
    }
    return(resultModel)    
}

getForestRemove()
# No negative results
#         Overall
# mpg  0.006325008
# cyl  0.019562726
# disp 0.050269930
# wt   0.065210330
# qsec 0.000000000
# am   0.041387607
# gear 0.085664931
# carb 0.000000000
```